# Various definitions of Order Embedding and Order Isomorphism

Tags: definition, order-theory

From my textbook, Wikipedia, and other sources from the Internet, I have come across various definitions of Order Embedding and those of Order Isomorphism, so I'm very confused about them.

My questions:

1. Are those definitions actually equivalent ?
2. Are there a preferred definition for Order Embedding and that for Order Isomorphism?

Thank you so much!

---

Def$-1$ of **Order Embedding**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be posets. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order embedding** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if the following condition holds: $$(1):\forall x,y\in A:x \preccurlyeq_A y\iff f(x) \preccurlyeq_B f(y)$$

Def$-2$ of **Order Embedding**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be posets. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order embedding** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if both of the following conditions hold:
>
> \begin{align}&(1): f\text{ is injective}\\&(2): \forall x,y\in A:x \prec_A y \iff f(x)\prec_B f(y)\end{align}

Def$-1$ of **Order Isomorphism**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be posets. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order isomorphism** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if both of the following conditions hold:
>
> \begin{align}&(1): f\text{ is surjective}\\&(2): \forall x,y\in A:x \preccurlyeq_A y\iff f(x)\preccurlyeq_B f(y)\end{align}

Def$-2$ of **Order Isomorphism**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be posets. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order isomorphism** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if both of the following conditions hold:
>
> \begin{align}&(1): f\text{ is bijective}\\&(2): \forall x,y\in A:x \prec_A y \iff f(x)\prec_B f(y)\end{align}

Def$-1$ of **Order Isomorphism** between **tosets**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be **tosets**. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order isomorphism** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if both of the following conditions hold:
>
> \begin{align}&(1): f\text{ is surjective}\\&(2): \forall x,y\in A:x \prec_A y \implies f(x)\prec_B f(y)\end{align}

Def$-2$ of **Order Isomorphism** between **tosets**:

> Let $(A,\prec_A),(B,\prec_B)$ be **tosets**. A mapping $f:A\to B$ is an **order isomorphism** from $A$ into $B$ if and only if both of the following conditions hold:
>
> \begin{align}&(1): f\text{ is bijective}\\&(2): \forall x,y\in A:x \preccurlyeq_A y \implies f(x)\preccurlyeq_B f(y)\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Order embedding

$\mbox{def 1}\iff\mbox{def 2}.$

Note that the first definition implies injective:

Given $f:A\to B$ such that $\forall x,y\in A:x \preccurlyeq_A y\iff f(x) \preccurlyeq_B f(y)$.

- $f$ is injective:

> $\forall x,y\in A \quad f(x)=f(y)\implies\begin{cases}f(x) \preccurlyeq_B f(y)\implies x \preccurlyeq_A y\\f(y) \preccurlyeq_B f(x)\implies y \preccurlyeq_A x\end{cases}{\mid}\implies x=y$

I am sure you can prove the rest.

I am not sure about "preferred definition" but when I first study this I learn with the second definition.

---

## Order Isomorphism

Again we have $\mbox{def 1}\iff\mbox{def 2}.$

First note that def 1 can be written as **surjective Order embedding** which implies it is bijective. I am sure you can prove that the fact one use $\preccurlyeq$ and the other $\prec$ does not matter.

I am not sure about "preferred definition" but when I first study this I learn with the second definition.

---

Order Isomorphism between tosets is basically the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirm @Holo!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for order embedding 1 uses <= and 2 uses <.
Usually orders are reflexive.  Strict orders are
not reflexive.  < is a strict order, <= is not.
For example 5 <= 5 but not 5 < 5.

The two definitions are equivalent.
Reflexive orders are prefered.

Comment: "Reflexive ordered are preferred"? By whom? Why? Well-orders are not reflexive usually, and those are *very* commonly used everywhere.